# Route bridge traffic thru a specific interface in my KVM server

Tags: linux, networking, routing, kvm

My setup is as depicted in the image.[image: My KVM setup]

My VMs sit on both virtual subnets. Currently, all traffic from both virtual subnets flows thru **ens1** since that is the primary interface with a route metric of 100. **ens2** has a route metric of 200. I would like the in/out traffic from virtual subnet 2 to flow thru **ens2**. What do I need to do to achieve that?

For those with additional curiosity, this KVM box is on a bare metal host in AWS. I have put in entries in the VPC route table to direct inbound traffic for these 2 subnets to the **ens1** interface. The outbound traffic for both subnets to the VPC flows thru **ens1** as well. All VMs can communicate with the host and other hosts in the VPC. Things are working, but not exactly how I want it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.